# Template for component construction in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, code-snippets, xamarin-studio, code-templates

Programming in C# in Unity requires tremendous amounts of boiler-plate. This is partly due to C#, but also due to design decisions in the engine itself.

The fact that I cannot construct MonoBehaviours myself means I need to write code as the following to enforce correct initialization:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int a;
    private float b;
    private string c;
    private List<int> lst;

    public static MyClass Construct (int a, float b, string c,List<int> lst)
    {
        //Boiler-plate stuff
        var go = new GameObject ();
        var mc = go.AddComponent<MyClass> ();

        /*
         * This part is fugly. The static method is setting
         * fields on the object. The responsibility to be
         * fully initialized after construction should
         * lie on the object. 
         * I could easily forget to set fields from the
         * outside.
         */
        mc.a = a;
        mc.b = b;
        mc.c = c;
        mc.lst = lst;

        return mc;
    }

    //Same as above, but this time without constructing a new GameObject.
    public static MyClass AddTo (GameObject go,int a, float b, string c,List<int> lst)
    {
        var mc = go.AddComponent<MyClass> ();

        mc.a = a;
        mc.b = b;
        mc.c = c;
        mc.lst = lst;

        return mc;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to create a code-snippet for this in Xamarin studio to reduce boiler-plate, or any other fancy tricks to automate the process of writing these functions?

My unfinished attempt currently looks like this with Xamarin editor-templates:

```
public static $classname$ Construct(){
}
```

Where $classname$ calls a function to get the name of current class. I don't think it's actually possible to list the identifiers of the class in the function header.

Just to pre-empt people: I know it is possible to create classes that don't derive from MonoBehaviour, but let's assume that this class actually needs the functionality of a GameObject.

Comment: the fact that you can't use "new MonoBehaviour" is causing a lot of problems in the company where i work. the main problem was with the save-games (we decided to use BinaryFormatter, but that requires a constructor for de-serialization). our current solution is that classes derived from MonoBehaviour keep their variables in another class that can be created with "new". the down side is that we have to make some ugly properties for accessing them to keep the rest of the code clean.

Comment: If you follow the Unity talks by one of the indie game dev companies (I forget which) you'll find they decouple their code from being tied specifically to Unity.  Not only does it allow you to rapidly prototype outside of Unity it allows you the Unity behaviour classes to be nothing more than proxies to your external code.  If you follow this behaviour then there is no reason to create the code in any fashion you want.

Comment: Using the engine "as-a-library" does seem quite attractive, but I'm guessing that I'll lose a lot of functionality from prefabs in this way. Also, the boiler plate will probably move somewhere else. I miss some powerful constructs like Scala's traits and its case-classes.
Any comments on the xamarin code-template thing?

Comment: Found the YouTube video - _[Unite 2013 - Nurturing Large Projects: How We Structured Hardware: Shipbreakers - Utilising MVVM in Unity](https://youtu.be/q9aeNtKKXeo?t=16m)_.  At the 13:00 mark is essentially where they start to talk about abstracting out their code to have a Unity-independent layer so as to implement a MVVM system.  **Prefabs** - it does not mean you'll do away with prefabs, nor other important features of Unity.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for some factory pattern.

Depending on the context, I have 3 suggestions:

**1 Prefabs**

Avoid boiler plate code, that's why is so common to use prefabs and instantiate them. It's the [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) pattern. Declare a set of serialized properties and instantiate a clone of the current prototype (that's what you are trying to do by code).

**2 Initialize in Awake**

If your objects are always initialized with a defined set of value, initialize them in Awake rather than in constructors.
If they're not , well every component should in any case provide the relevant constructors overloads(as init method, since you cannot rely on constructor), or be wrapped inside a factory.

**3 Use lambda**

If you still prefer, or for some reasons need to, to stick with a procedural object creation, you can avoid declare methods for every class and simply pass an responsible for initializing the object. Something like:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    public int foobar;
}

public static T CreateAndAttach<T>(Action<T> init)
     where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject go = new GameObject();
    T t = go.AddComponent<T>();

    init(t);
    return t;
}

//usage
CreateAndAttach<Test>(t => { t.foobar = 10; });
```

> The fact that I cannot construct MonoBehaviours myself means I need to
>   write code as the following to enforce correct initialization

The fact is that `MonoBehaviours` are C# wrappers for component that resides in the `C++` side of the engine, and it's **the engine that owns their life time**. They are de facto resources you ask for and possibly release (like other resources such as textures, meshes,..).

Comment: The lambda one is the least of evils IMHO, but noises up the syntax somewhat.

Comment: @Felix: could you provide and code snippet of how you would like to instantiate and intialize objects?

Comment: The two static functions in my original posts would be examples.

Comment: Ok, but you are limited to the parameters exposed by such functions and forced to define each one for each type. I guess if this is the use case the more similar approach is using lambda.